# Construct an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $D$ is associative division algebras over field $F$.

I need to construct an isomorphism of algebras

$$\text{Mat}(n,D)\simeq D\otimes_F \text{Mat}(n,F).$$

I can feel, that it ought to be quite easy, but I have failed to do it so far.

Comment: Sorry but what's the definition of "a body over a field $F$"? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean “division algebra over $F$”? This is how the French “corps” is usually translated into English.

Comment: Yes, I mean associative division algebras over F.

Comment: Can you construct a map in either direction?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Every element of $\text{Mat}(n, F)\otimes_F D$ can be written uniquely as sum of simple tensors. So that $\text{Mat}(n, F)\otimes_F D \to \text{Mat}(n, D)$ can be defined by

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E_{i,j} \otimes_F a_{i,j} \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E_{i,j} a_{i,j}$$

where $E_{i,j}$ is matrix having $1$ in the $i,j$'th coordinate, and $0$ elsewhere.

Since both have same dimension, it is sufficient to prove surjectivity. For any $M' = (a_{i,j}) \in \text{Mat}(n, D)$, we have $E_{i,j} \otimes a_{i,j} \mapsto M'$

Comment: Many thanks, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $F$-bilinear mapping $f\colon D\times\operatorname{Mat}(n,F)\to\operatorname{Mat}(n,D)$ given by the obvious action:
$$
(d,[a_{ij}])\mapsto [da_{ij}]
$$
where $d\in D$ and $[a_{ij}]\in\operatorname{Mat}(n,F)$. This gives an $F$-linear homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon D\otimes_F\operatorname{Mat}(n,F)\to\operatorname{Mat}(n,D)
$$
and it's easy to check it's also a homomorphism of algebras: just do the verification that
$$
\varphi\bigl((d_1\otimes A_1)(d_2\otimes A_2)\bigr)
=\varphi(d_1\otimes A_1)\cdot\varphi(d_2\otimes A_2)
$$
which boils down to showing that
$$
f(d_1d_2,A_1A_2)=f(d_1,A_1)\cdot f(d_2,A_2)
$$
The map $\varphi$ is actually a homomorphism of left $D$-vector spaces, as it's easy to verify, and it is obviously surjective. Since the two $D$-vector spaces have the same dimension $n^2$ (find a basis of $D\otimes_F\operatorname{Mat}(n,F)$ to check this), $\varphi$ is also injective.